# vb.net login/register form does not work

Tags: vb.net

So I am working on login/register form in vb.net
I created database and login works good but my register form does not want to insert the values into database. Here is the code that I have behind it. I'm not sure what is being wrong.

```
Public Class frmRegister
Private Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
    txtUsernameRegister.Focus()

    If txtUsernameRegister.Text = "" Or txtPasswordRegister.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Username And Password!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        txtUsernameRegister.Focus()
    Else
        Dim sqlConnection1 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\userDB.accdb")

        Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        sqlConnection1.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userDB (username, password) VALUES ('" & txtUsernameRegister.Text & "', '" & txtPasswordRegister.Text & "')"
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1


        sqlConnection1.Close()

        frmLogin.Show()
        Hide()
    End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: a [mcve] would be great too. also **never** store plain text passwords.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because it never executes the INSERT statement. You assign `cmd.CommandText`, and then close the connection. How do you expect it to save the data when you never do anything to save the data? Magic? Also, your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection which could expose your entire data to risk. Search here for *[vba.net] parameterized queries* and learn how to do it properly **now**, before you get used to the bad coding practices.

Answer (score 0):

To formalise the suggestion in Ken White's comment, you need to call `ExecuteNonQuery` on your command in order to actually execute it against the database.

I must echo the sentiments regarding parameters too. Apart from the fact that some values might cause an exception to be thrown, a malicious user could potentially delete the entire contents of your database.

Also, it is not a good idea to store plain text passwords in a database for security reasons.  You should look into hashing to learn how it's done right.